# Fixing western digital external hard drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive, repair

Alright, yesterday I was in my Linux box copying some data, it finished, I went away for a while and came back, it finished copying the data but the LED kept moving on, so I had to force a shutdown.

Now it just doesn't load up, nothing. Is there an app to analyze my HD or something and repair it?

Note: I'm on my Windows 7 partition now, it also doesn't load up, it registers the USB, but in "My computer", there is no device there :(

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds exactly how my hard drive died. If it's not spinning up, no software in the world will be able to scan it. Send it to the pros if you value your data.

Comment: sadly... it's not spinning :( I don't know how much it costs to send it to the pros (probably a lot)

Comment: Look at anything from $300 to $1000, depending on the damage. That's what our customers in the shop have been quoted in the past. Unfortunately you'll only know when they open it up. I personally spent around $500 on having mine recovered.

Comment: And that is how I learnt the hard way about backups.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it is the power supply or the usb chip in the enclosure that fails, you can remove the hard drive from the enclosure and connect the drive to another PC using a hard drive to USB adapter, they are fairly cheap.

[Adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152&cm_re=usb_hard_drive_adapter-_-12-119-152-_-Product)

You can usually find video's for opening the enclosure on youtube for your specific model